# MongoDB aggregating multiple objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to create a MongoDB query where I get a conversation between two users. Basically my conversation object is like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123"),
    "from" : ObjectId("456"),
    "to" : ObjectId("789"),
    "content" : "Hi!",
    "createdAt" : 1558037545568.0
}
```

I wanna bring up their conversation sorted by `createdAt` descending and also bring their user objects together. I know I need to use a `$lookup` for search on the `users` query, but I have some questions:

1. How I can create a `$lookup` operation that will bring both of the users?
2. How to manage it in the way that sometimes the user `456` is the `from` user and sometimes the `to` user? Same for the user `789`. I didn't get it too much.

This is the current query that brings everything ordered without the user objects:

```
db.getCollection('messages').aggregate([{
    $match: {
      $or: [
        { from: ObjectId("456") },
        { to: ObjectId("789") },
        { from: ObjectId("789") },
        { to: ObjectId("456") }
      ]
    }
  }, {
    $sort: { createdAt: -1 }
  }])
```

Thank y'all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "normalize" your documents by adding `users` array which will contain `from` and `to` sorted ascending. Then it's easier to run `$match` on that array (sorting arguments),

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
    $addFields: {
        users: [ { $min: [ "$from", "$to" ] }, { $max: [ "$from", "$to" ] } ]
    } 
    },
    {
        $match: { users: [ "456", "789" ] }
    }
])
```

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) can be run directly on an array so following syntax should work as a next step:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "users",
        localField: "users",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "users"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @mickl! Also, I'm struggling now to replace those results into the rootObject. Based on your solution, I have an array of `users` and I want to replace them into the main object: the `from` attribute will be one of the user object and the `to` attribute as well. I was looking to the `replaceRoot` pipeline, but I didn't find any way to compare whatever I have in the `users` array with my main attributes. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: @Kiwanax could you describe that as a separate question and paste a link here ? I will try to take a look later